# How can i add two double values without exponential in android

Tags: java, android

Please help me to solve this. I trying to get value from textview and stored as string. Then it converts to double. While converting up to 7 characters functioning normally but if i try to add more than 7 result is 1.23456789E8. Here is my code

```
String value = tvInput.getText().toString();
\\tvInput is my textView
Double result = 0.0;
Double input1=0.0;
Double input2=0.0;
input=Double.parseDouble(value);
result = input1 + input2;
tvInput.setText(Double.toString(result));
```

if i give input1 value as 1234567 and input2 as 1234567 i am getting correct result but if give input1 as 12345678 and input2 as 3. the output is 1.2345681E7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you get is correct, the issue is with the way you print it.

You're relying on toString for a double output; if you want to guarantee not to have an exponential notation, you should format it using a [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), or with String.format;

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("############");
tvInput.setText(myFormatter.format(result));
```

Also see [the format documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Joeri Hendrickx i fixed my issue

Comment: @sam np. If this solves your issue, accept the answer.  Click the checkmark icon on the left of the answer so that it becomes green.  Thanks!

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx hahahah Nice Answer as well as Nice explanation to accept the answer.The line "Click the checkmark icon on the left of the answer so that it becomes green" is just superb :P

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is consistent with the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29). You could use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Either `12345678` and `1.2345678E7` are exactly the same number. No trouble with that

Your trouble is with the representation, if E>6 then [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) use scientific notation. You may want to use NumberFormat for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use String.format: [example](http://ideone.com/exsa8)

```
class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
     String i1 = "12345678";
     String i2 = "3";
     double d1 = Double.parseDouble(i1);
     double d2 = Double.parseDouble(i2);
     double d = d1 + d2;
     System.out.println( String.format("%f", d) ); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't use Integer instead?

```
String value = tvInput.getText().toString();
\\tvInput is my textView
int result = 0;
int input1 = 0;
int input2 = 0;
input=Integer.parseInt(value);
result = input1 + input2;
tvInput.setText(Integer.toString(result));
```